# A q-rious identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, q-analogs

Let $[x]_q=\frac{1-q^x}{1-q}$,  $[n]_q!=[1]_q[2]_q\cdots[n]_q$ and ${\binom{x}{n}}_{q}=\frac{[x]_q[x-1]_q\cdots[x-n+1]_q }{[n]_q!}$.

Computer experiments suggest that
$$\det \left(q^\binom{i-j}{2}\left(\binom{i+r}{j}_{q}x+\binom{i+r-j}{j}_{q}\right)\right)_{i,j = 0}^{n - 1} = (1+x)^n$$

Any idea how to prove this?

Comment: I couldn't decide whether to upvote for an interesting question, downvote for a terrible pun, or try to upvote twice as appreciation for the terrible pun. :)

Comment: I bet he got it from ArXiv.  Gerhard "It's Not The First Time" Paseman, 2019.09.17.

Comment: "q-rious and q-riouser," by S. Ole Warnaar and Wadmin Zudlin.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke's reference, clickable:  [Warnaar and Zudlin - $q$-rious and $q$-riouser](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.07045).

Comment: The pun seems to be older than that. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32775/curious-q-analogues#comment74059_32775

Comment: Is there no q-re for these puns?

Comment: @Wolfgang: But notice that comment was posted by the same Wadim Zudilin (whose name I mispelled above).

Comment: The title is too q-te by a mile

Comment: But he did take his q-e from Wadim Zudilin.

Comment: Someone ought to q-rate these comments.

Comment: The leading term in $x$ is not so hard to calculate...

Comment: In the mean-time I found a proof by reducing it to
$\det \left(q^\binom{i-j}{2}\binom{i+r}{j}_{q} \right)_{i,j = 0}^{n - 1} = 1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be the matrix involved in the problem and let $L_n=\left((-1)^{i-j}\binom{i}{j}_q\right)_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$. 
Observe that $L_n$ is lower-triangular with 1's in the diagonal.  Multiplying, we have: 
$$L_nA_n=\left(x\,u_{i,j}(r)+u_{i,j}(r-j)\right)_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$$
where 
$$u_{i,j}(r)=\sum_{k=0}^i(-1)^{i-k}q^{\binom{k-j}{2}}\binom{i}{k}_q\,\binom{k+r}{j}_q\,.$$

Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_{i,j}(r)&=&\sum_{k=0}^i(-1)^{i-k}q^{\binom{k-j}{2}}\binom{i}{i-k}_q\,\binom{k+r}{k+r-j}_q \\
&=&(-1)^{r+i-j}\,q^{\binom{r+1}{2}}\,\sum_{k=0}^i q^{k(k+r-j)}\binom{i}{i-k}_q\,\binom{-j-1}{k+r-j}_q \\
&=&(-1)^{r+i-j}\,q^{\binom{r+1}{2}}\,\sum_{k=0}^i q^{k(k+r-j)}\binom{i}{i-k}_q\,\binom{-j-1}{k+r-j}_q \\
&=&(-1)^{r+i-j}\,q^{\binom{r+1}{2}}\,\binom{i-j-1}{i-j+r}_q
=q^{\binom{i-j}{2}}\,\binom{r}{j-i}_q\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $u_{i,j}(r)=0$ when $i>j$ and $u_{i,i}(r)=1$.
Thus $L_nA_n$ is upper triangular with $x+1$  as elements of the diagonal.

Answer (score 6):

In the mean-time I have found a proof:

First write  Vandermonde’s identity $$\sum_{j=0}^k q^{(k-j)(i+r-j)}\binom{s-r}{k-j}_{q}\binom{i+r}{j}_{q}=\binom{i+s}{k}_{q}$$ in the form
$$\sum_{j=0}^k q^{\frac{(j-k)(j-k-1-2r)}{2}}\binom{s-r}{k-j}_{q}q^{\binom{i-j}{2}}\binom{i+r}{j}_{q}=q^{\binom{i-k}{2}}\binom{i+s}{k}_{q}$$ and then replace $s$ by $r-k.$
The elements of the first column of the matrix $$A_{n}=\left(q^\binom{i-j}{2}\left(\binom{i+r}{j}_{q}x+\binom{i+r-j}{j}_{q}\right)\right)_{i,j = 0}^{n - 1} $$ are $q^\binom{i}{2}(x+1).$ By linearity we  get  $\det{A_n}=(x+1)\det{B_n}$, where the first column of $B_n$ consist of the numbers $q^{\binom{i}{2}}$.
Then by the above identity we can reduce the second column to $q^{\binom{i-1}{2}}\binom{i+r}{1}_{q}(1+x)$ and again factor out $(1+x)$. Iterating this procedure we get  $\det{A_n}=(x+1)^n\det{C_n}$ with
$C_n= \left(q^\binom{i-j}{2}\binom{i+r}{j}_{q} \right)_{i,j = 0}^{n - 1}$.

To prove  $\det{C_n}=1$   observe that $$q^{\binom{i+1-j}{2}}\binom{i+1+r}{j}_{q}-q^{i}q^\binom{i-j}{2}\binom{i+r}{j}_{q}=q^\binom{i-(j-1)}{2}\binom{r+i}{j-1}_{q}.$$
Therefore by subtracting $q^{i}$ times row $i$ from row ${i+1}$   we get that $\det{C_n}= \det{ \begin{pmatrix} 1& * \\ 0 & C_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}}=\dots=1.$